# aframe's object inside iframe, object's obj.object3D not defined

Tags: javascript, iframe, aframe

Hi I am trying to create a iframe that takes code from the parent window but the JS code that it takes is not able to access the `document.getElementById("obj1").object3D` ie the object3D (three.js object).

I am appending the js code at the end of the body and then reloading the iframe.

I also checked the iframe window at iframe.io and the result was same object3D not defined.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: update: the objects at aframe.io iframe's window are giving out their object3D

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.parent.document.getElementById('obj1');`